# why is jqwidgets jquery-number-input.js is not working as expected when existing text inside textbox is selected using "control+a"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I created a textbox using jqwidget's jquery-number-input.js library.
The created textbox will accept decimal till 2 digits with "$" symbol as prefix.
When i selected the existing text(ex: $123.12) inside the created textbox with "control+a" key combination and enter new values, resultant text is coming with previous decimal values instead on clearing the decimal values to zeros.

please refer to jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0bgz65ze/

html :        `<div id='jqxNumberInput'></div>`

javascript:   `$("#jqxNumberInput").jqxNumberInput({
              width: '250px',
              height: '25px',
              theme: 'energyblue',
              spinButtons: false,
              decimalDigits: 2,
              symbol: '$',
              inputMode: 'simple'
              });`

1. Enter some value in the fiddle say 123.45
2. click inside the textbox and press "control+a" key combination.
3. enter 123

Result is $123.05 instead of $123.00

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be OK now. May be that issue is fixed by http://www.jqwidgets.com/

Comment: It is working now. But if "Control+X" is used to delete the content of the text box,the text box is not editable anymore. Thanks

Comment: yeah, because it's not supported :)